# AVVideoPreviewLayer gravity for iPad

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am working on iOS camera app where I would like to show camera with black bars on side meaning without filling full screen with aspect ratio.

I learned that preview layer can be used to control video dimensions and I am able to add/remove black bars on side using `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect`  and `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill` property respectively.

It’s working for iPhone but somehow same code is not working on iPad

I tried to print active format which get used during iPhone and iPad run. Both looks same

On iPhone

```
<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x2839d2490 
'vide'/'420v' 4032x3024, { 3- 30 fps}, HRSI:4032x3024, fov:57.716, max zoom:189.00 (upscales @1.00), AF System:2, ISO:23.0-1840.0, SS:0.000013-0.333333>
```

On iPad

```
 <AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x2833bf630
 'vide'/'420v' 4032x3024, { 3- 30 fps}, HRSI:4032x3024, fov:63.301, max zoom:189.00 (upscales @1.00), AF System:2, ISO:22.0-2112.0, SS:0.000020-0.333333>
```

Open questions

1. Why this is not working on IPad? Why I am not able to see black bars?
2. On iPhone when I print `previewLayer.frame.size.width` I always do get same value with or without black bars. I am expecting smaller width when I show black bars on sides. I am missing anything here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `videoGravity` only specifies how the layer fits the video frames inside its bounds. It doesn't cause the layer to change its dimensions – it will always keep the frame you assign it via UIKit.

I assume you show the layer full-screen. On an iPhone, this will show black bars for this video format since the screen doesn't have a 4:3 ratio. Most iPads do, however. That's why no bars are necessary on iPad; the video fits the screen entirely.

Comment: So is there any way I can show black bars on iPad? Or do I need to use different active format for this? And secondly on Iphone how do I get width and height of camera preview excluded black bars? When I do previewLayer.frame.size I always do get same size regardless of what I set gravity.

Comment: The layer always has the size you (or UIKit's layout system) gives it. If you followed Apple's examples then it's the size of the view it's embedded in. However, the layer will resize and fit/fill the video frames from the camera for displaying them inside its bounds – and this depending on the `videoGravity`.

Comment: To get the size of the video frames you have to check the format. In this case, they are `4032x3024`, which coincides with the iPad's screen aspect ratio – so no black bars. If you pick one of the video session presets for your `AVCaptureSession` for instance, it would likely be a 16:9 format that would cause black bars. Out of curiosity: Why do you _want_ black bars anyway?

Comment: For Iphone I do see black bars because I am using .resizeAspect and then it adds black bar. But here if I get previewLayer.frame it’s still showing same which was with full screen camera. There is no difference I see when black bar added. I would like to get size without black bar. 

I wanted to some image cropping and wanted to see how some stuff will work with black bars 4:3